# Is it possible to use a space-filling curve to index a 2D grid which is not $2^x$ by $2^y$?

Tags: data-structures

I am working on a project which needs to traverse a 2d spatial grid, and would like to use a space-filling curve indexing scheme.  Unfortunately, I have no guarantee that the input grid will be a power of two along either dimension.  In fact, it may be just barely over a power of two in some cases.  Virtually extending the grid to be a power of two in size may use too much memory (it is a very large grid).  Is it still possible to use a space-filling curve, such as a [Morton curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), to index this grid?

Answer (score 2):

What kind of indexing do you need? If it is just a lookup, your can interleave the bits of you coordinates to get a z-ordered Morton value. These could be stored in binary trie (critbit-tree) that uses prefix sharing. Traversing the tree gives you Morton-order, and the possible prefix sharing should reduce memory consumption.
I implemented one in Java: [critbit](https://github.com/tzaeschke/critbit)

If you also need geometric queries (kNN, window queries, range queries), you could try the [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org), it's like a bit like quadtree, but uses prefix sharing like a trie and some other things to be much more efficient (memory and speed) than a quadtree. The tree uses internally a Morton ordering so a full traversal or Window queries will always return Morton-ordered results.